# how fix calling on custom actionlink method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i create this custom actionlink

```
public static IHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int userId, string controller, string linkText, string action)
    {
        int userID = userId;
        bool isAllowed = checkPermission(userID,action,controller);
        if (isAllowed == false)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, action);
    }
```

i am try to call this method as 
Helper.CustomActionLink(4,"myController","text","MyAction")
but it asking me to pass first argument also 'this HtmlHelper htmlHelper' how i fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
@Html.CustomActionLink(4,"myController","text","MyAction")
```